# Jackson JPA @Version Not serialized

Tags: jackson, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have my JPA Entity as below

```
@Entity
public class OptionsEntity implements Serializable {



    @Id
    @Column(name="OptionNumber",
            nullable=false,
            insertable=true,
            updatable=true,
            length=20)
    private String optionNumber;

    @Basic
    @Column(name="OptionName",
            nullable=false,
            insertable=true,
            updatable=true,
            length=100)
    private String optionName;

    @Basic
    @Column(name="OptionStatusCode",
            nullable=true,
            insertable=true,
            updatable=true,
            length=20)
    private String optionStatusCode;

    @JsonProperty
    @Version
    @Column(name="VersionNumber",
            nullable=false,
            insertable=true,
            updatable=true)
    private Integer versionNumber;

}
```

I wanted the versionNumber to be present in the response body. But, it is being ignored for some reason.

I'm using Spring Boot along with Spring Data repositories to retrieve the data. I'm not sure if it is playing any role here.

Spring Data speaks about ETags. But, having Spring Security involved along with Spring Data seems to be a complicated procedure (Due to cache headers) and also when working with a collection of entities on the client side (JavaScipt). Thus, I wanted to handle the resource versioning myself.

Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks nothing wrong. Even the @JsonProperty isn't needed, I think. Did you try changing Integer to primitive int? I assume you have public getters and setters for all the fields.

Answer (score 0):

REST has dedicated means to deal with resource state, explicit headers to conditionally trigger requests based on that resource state.

So what Spring Data REST does, it translates the means of the persistent store to express that into means of REST. That includes to translate the artificially (for the sake of the persistent store) introduced properties (identifiers, version attributes) into the REST equivalents (self URIs, ETags). Using the version property as ETag then requires it two be removed for multiple reasons:

- it's been artificially introduced in the first place, so actually isn't part of the representation of the resource
- its purpose is achieved by different means, and thus it needs to be "moved" to those means
- keeping it in the representation would create the risk of mismatches between what's in the ETag and the representation. If the client mixes them up for some reason, how's the server supposed to determine the actual intention of the client?

The specifics of the handling of `@Version` properties are described in the [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#conditional).

Comment: Hi Oliver.. Thank you for the reply. ETag seems to be a nice idea.. But our clients dont like that idea of additional headers as the framework they use.. Telerik Kendo UI doesnt support ETag functionality. Further, when I have a collection of elements in the response, I'm not sure how the ETAG concept works.. And lastly, I need to disable Spring Security Cache headers for ETags to be exposed, which is not liked by our security experts.. So with mixed bag of down feedback, my only choice is to deal with version number myself.. Any thoughts on how to do it?

Comment: Either fix the clients or don't use Spring Data REST and rather build the server side on your own.

Comment: :( actually.. in this case.. I'm bypassing SDR.. the response is from a REST Controller... and the save to that entity/entities is going to be sent to the controller as well... but it looks like SDR config is kicking in too.. SDR saves me a lot of time in many other areas..

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. As my understanding gets better..

ETags are a cool feature. Especially because the client doesnt have to spin through the JSON schema to get the version number property. And ETags are supposed to be universally recognized.

Now, the problem lies with a collection of entities. We cannot obviously have an ETag set on the response, unless we manage the collection as another entity for itself. This is a problem if there is a scenario where a search result containing a collection of entities and could potentially expose the complete object to the client.

Per SDR's lead above, there doesnt seem to be a straight forward way to bypass this. The below piece of code in PersistentEntityJackson2Module is the reason for skipping the version id property.

```
            for (BeanPropertyWriter writer : builder.getProperties()) {

            // Skip exported associations
            PersistentProperty<?> persistentProperty = findProperty(writer.getName(), entity, beanDesc);

            if (persistentProperty == null) {
                result.add(writer);
                continue;
            }

            if (associationLinks.isLinkableAssociation(persistentProperty)) {
                continue;
            }

            // Skip ids unless explicitly configured to expose
            if (persistentProperty.isIdProperty() && !configuration.isIdExposedFor(entity.getType())) {
                continue;
            }

            if (persistentProperty.isVersionProperty()) {
                continue; ===> This causes version number to be stripped off.. 
            }

            result.add(writer);
        }
```

Obviously we can write our own alternative to bypass the above code.. but thats something stupid.. so I ended up doing something below so that everything else could be smooth..

```
@Version
@Column(name="VersionNumber",
        nullable=false,
        insertable=true,
        updatable=true)
private Integer versionNumber;

@JsonProperty(value = "versionNumber")
@Transient
private Integer version;

public Integer getVersion(){
    return (versionNumber != null) ? versionNumber : version;
}

public void setVersion(Integer version){
    if(version != null)
        setVersionNumber(version);
}

public void setVersionNumber(Integer version){
    this.versionNumber = version;
    this.version = version;
}
```

I opened up a feature request in SDR project to handle such a scenario [DATAREST-636](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-636).

Happy coding..